# Replacing backslashes, forward slashes and double forward slashes with double backslashes

Tags: c#, regex, string

If I have the following string

`"/test\\dso\dsa"`

how can I convert it, using Regex, to

`"\\test\\dso\\dsa"`?

If I try something like

```
Regex.Replace (FilePath, @"/|\\", @"\\");
```

it creates a mess in the middle (since it adds the `\\` twice, thus adding `\\\\\\\\`). How can I make it only match one backslash at a time?

Comment: i think `\d` in your input  would be treated as an escape sequence.

Comment: Is the string declared as a verbatim string literal, e.g. `var s = @"/test\\dso\dsa"`?

Comment: @stribizhev Yes. The function is called with `(@"/test\\dso\dsa")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var FilePath = @"/test\\dso\dsa";
var myres = Regex.Replace(FilePath, @"[\\/]+", @"\\");
```

Output:

```
\\test\\dso\\dsa
```

The regex `[\\/]+` matches 1 or more `\` or `/` characters that are then replaced with two `\` symbols.

The problem with `@"/|\\"` regex is that it matches each `\` or `/` one by one, thus resulting in more replacements than you need. Also, it is not a good idea to use separate symbols as alternatives since there is more backtracking involved. The best practice is adding them into a character class `[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
Regex.Replace (FilePath, @"/|\\{1,2}", "\\\\");
```

`\\{1,2}` will match a single or double backslashes,.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sU1mJ4/2)